# What should be my virtual function's prototype?

Tags: c++, oop, function-prototypes

Let's say I have an abstract base class `Base` with a virtual function `doSomething()`

There are two derived classes, one of which takes no parameters in `doSomething()` while the other takes a structure and an integer as a parameter.

A function in another class (SomeClass) calls `doSomething()` using a `Base*` variable. 
It also needs to pass the parameters i mentioned for `DerivedTwo`.

How do i choose the prototype without using an if-else to check for the object's class at run-time?

Thank you.

```
    class Base {
      public:
      void virtual doSomething(); 
    }

    class DerivedOne : Base {
      public:
      void doSomething(int a,struct b);
    }

    class DerivedTwo : Base {
      public:
      void doSomething();
    }
```

Comment: Can you be a bit more concrete than `Base`, `DerivedOne` and `DerivedTwo`? The way I'd solve this is to simply make `Base::doSomething()` accept a `struct` and an `int`. But if the prototypes are different, I'm inclined to think there's a fundamental issue with the design. `if`/`else` statements are almost always the wrong answer to this type of situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this would be:

```
class Base {
public:
    Base();
    virtual ~Base();
    virtual void doSomething();
};

class DerivedOne : public Base {
public:
    DerivedOne();
    void doSomethingElse(int a,struct b);
};

class DerivedTwo : public Base {
public:
    DerivedTwo();
    virtual void doSomething();
};
```

You could then use `dynamic_cast` to determine the type at runtime since you seem to have a type-conditional expression someplace in `SomeClass`. The methods are not equal and fundamentally distinct. Also, `DerivedOne::doSomething` would hide `Base::doSomething`.

**Update**

As the others had already stated, it's often a bad smell if your program relies on type-conditional expressions. Since your example does not have enough context to offer appropriate solutions, it's hard for us to help you in this regard. If you are interested in removing the type-conditional, one of many potential solutions to this problem would be:

```
class Base {
public:
    Base();
    virtual ~Base();
    virtual void doSomething();
};

class DerivedOne : public Base {
public:
    DerivedOne();
    // ...
    virtual void doSomething(); // << no parameters required.
                                // they have moved to member data:
private:
    int a;
    b another;
};

class DerivedTwo : public Base {
public:
    DerivedTwo();
    virtual void doSomething();
};
```

then you could remove the type-conditional expression from your program. If you'd like help in this regard, feel free to ask here or open a new question if you feel it is more appropriate.

Comment: Type conditional code in the base class to test which derived class the instance is is a pretty major design flaw.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I agree with you *but* that's not the case here; the OP specified the type-condition occurs in the implementation of `SomeClass`.

Comment: It amounts to much the same since the target of the function call is a Base*. Anyway, I just wanted to point out that although this is the accepted answer, the original question and this direct answer have the whiff of bad design.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Derived type conditionals in `Base` are usually far worse than out in client code (IMO). Anyway, I agree that the form is bad in many cases, but we don't have enough context to determine or recommend a lesser evil.

Comment: David is right here, whether it is in `Base` or in caller's code, the fact is that if the type of `DerivedOne` must be known to call a different method/overload, it is clearly violating Liskov's substitution principle. It is important to note that an interface is not just the name of the methods, but also the *signature* and the *semantics*. I was once given an example: *A camera and a pistol both* shoot, *but beware of what you have in your hands before taking a self-portrait* And in this particular case, the interfaces are more disparate: `shoot(Picture&)`, `shoot(Bullet&)`.

Comment: @David I never disagreed that dynamic type-conditionals were bad, although my answer may have suggested that. I just didn't feel the need to echo In silico, junjanes, and David's comments and answers (everybody involved at that point). So... I'll be the final one to point that out =) I've updated my answer, it offers another alternative to dynamic type conditionals. Believe it or not, my codebase has been written without reliance on RTTI.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I'm not a fan of the design either. But this situation has arisen because we port our code to a couple of vendors. Each provide their own prototypes for their apis. So the complete design is not in my team's hands

Answer (score 4):

You are wanting to change the parameter list of a virtual method in a derived class. This cannot be done. Usually when you find yourself wanting to do this it indicates that your class hierarchy design is incorrect.

The naive attempts to tackle this usually involve adding something to the base class which is only meaningful for certain derived classes. This violates the principles of good design.

There are many different ways to tackle the issue more properly, but it's hard to advise on the basis of this artificially constructed example.

Comment: virtual method should use in case of over-riding not in case of over-hiding right ?

Answer (score 2):

If you need to pass these variables for both derived types, just declare them same everywhere, like this:

```
class Base {
  public:
  void virtual doSomething(int a,struct b); 
}

class DerivedOne : Base {
  public:
  void doSomething(int a,struct b);
}

class DerivedTwo : Base {
  public:
  void doSomething(int a,struct b);
}
```

If you need to use parameters for one type and not for the other type, then what you need is not a class hierarchy. You will need to elaborate your problem more in that case.

Comment: Thanks. Is it a good practice to pass no parameters in doSomething() and instead provide getters for them. They could be used if required by the derived class.

Comment: @Pramod: I can't make comments on whether not passing a parameters is good or bad practice based on this superficial example. It depends on your actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

Can we solve this problem like this? :

```
class Base {
  public:
  void virtual doSomething();
  void virtual doSomething(int a,struct b); 
}

class DerivedOne : Base {
  public:
  void doSomething(int a,struct b);
}

class DerivedTwo : Base {
  public:
  void doSomething();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in your exmple you can use RTTI instead of if/else so you instantiate DerivedOne and DerivedTwo then you cast the Base pointer to both (DerivedOne and DerivedTwo) so the result is one of them is NULL. then you check wether the desired Derived object is not NULL and if it is you call the function:

```
DerivedOne *pDrvOne=dynamic_cast<DerivedOne*>(pBase);
DerivedTwo *pDrvTwo=dynamic_cast<DerivedTwo*>(pBase);
then: if(pDrvOne)pDrvOne->deSo,ething(a,b); if(pDrvTwo) pDrvTwo->doSomething();
```

*** Remeber the use of RTTI will undermine the principles of polymorphism. 
in your example you didn't overload doSomething() in DerivedOne subclass: "to overload a function is to use the same signature(name of function and the same number and type of parameters)". but you just overload it in DerivedTwo. thus consider this example:

```
Base *pBs;
pBs=new DerivedOne; pBs->doSomething(a,b); the result a call to base doSomthing!!!
```

*The solution is to try to understand the problem your class is going to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Taras's example .. just add 'default values' to Base's and DerivedTwo's prototype in Taras's example. That way rest of the code which is using Base class or DerivedTwo class won't have to change.